# Too many params in URL - Routing ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Im searching the best way for manage long urls in routing. I have many actions which looks like this:

```
/a/b/c/d/e
```

the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "xxx",
            "{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}", 
            new { controller = "Xxx", action="Xxx"});
```

the controller:

```
public ActionResult Xxx(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) { ... }
```

any change in params gives multi-change in every route/action, and that is the problem. Its not elastic. Is there any possibility to map params to some object? Something that would look like:

```
public ActionResult Xxx(RouteParams rp) { ... }
```

Hmm... eventually I think that I could use the Action Filter to solve this:

```
private RouteParams rp;
public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext) {
  rp = new RouteParams(...);
}
```

but I dont like this solution

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object like you did and use ModelBinder to construct it instead of filter. The Default Model binder should work, if not then create a custom one.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your route settings the same, just create a new model with properties matching the parameters in the route settings:

```
public class XxxModel
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
    public int e { get; set; }
}
```

Then use XxxModel as your parameter in the action:

```
public ActionResult Xxx( XxxModel model )
{
   ...
}
```

a, b, c, d and e will be mapped to the properties in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "xxx",
            "{*params}", 
            new { controller = "Xxx", action="Xxx"});
```

and

```
public ActionResult Xxx(string params) { ... }
```

params will be one string (eg. 1/2/3/4/5)
you'll have to do a `params.Split("/")` and `Convert.ToInt32()` to the parameters.